# Ajax callbacks didn't return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to create an ajax function to get some params of the DB each time, but when I call the ajax method it is not returning correctly, when I do it debug the value was ok, but the return result isn't works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  function foo(mod){
    var uri="some url";

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: uri,
    }).done(function( data ) {
      return data;
    });
  }

  // alert to get the result is always printing undefined
  alert(foo("param_1"));

});
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: Why do u declare a function in document.ready ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Why not? It's a handy, contained, non-global scope. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder document.ready  - i would say -is  not the place for declaring functions (unless you _really_ need it only for that specific scope) but for doing stuff when you want to be sure that the dom is built.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It's purely a point of style whether you use the scope you already have there, or create a second scoping function to contain your code to avoid globals. There's zero harm in putting the code in the `ready` callback. (Well, no more harm than using `ready` at all, which I don't recommend if you control where your `script` tags go. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder let's say this : if it was the last code on his document - he could place it at the bottom with no document.ready at all. ( assuming of course no future `document.write` stuff etc...). :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Right, but he'd still want a scoping function to avoid creating needless globals. (And that's exactly what I do: A scoping function in a script tag at the end of the doc without `ready`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder for scoping he could use pure IIFE. no need for document.ready  for that.....(anyway - we agree :-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo` can't *return* the result of the ajax call, because the ajax call is *asynchronous*. `foo` returns before the call completes. Moreover, the `return` in your `done` handler returns from the `done` handler, not `foo`.

You'll need to have `foo` accept a callback, and then call that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


  function foo(mod, callback){
    var uri="some url";

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: uri,
    }).done(function( data ) {
      callback(data);
    });
  }

  // alert to get the result is always printing undefined
  foo("param_1", function( data ) {
      alert(data);
  });

});
```

Or if you're really do no processing on it *at all* before giving it to the callback, you could supply `callback` to `done` directly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


  function foo(mod, callback){
    var uri="some url";

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: uri,
    }).done(callback);
  }

  // alert to get the result is always printing undefined
  foo("param_1", function( data ) {
      alert(data);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set async as false, but instead I recommend you to implement success and error handlers that can work async

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function foo(mod) {
        var uri = "some url";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: uri,
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        });
    }

    function successHandler(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        // Handle your data here
        console.log(data);
        //alert(data);
    }

    function errorHandler(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Magic
    }

    // alert to get the result is always printing undefined
    //alert(foo("param_1"));
    foo("param_1");
});
```